# Odoo reporting I want to insert comma in t-option float_time

Tags: html, xml, odoo, odoo-13

"I have a variable ot10_total with a value of 1758.92. I successfully added commas to format it using the code `<span t-esc="'{0:,.2f}'.format(ot10_total)"/>, and it displays as 1,758.92.`

Next, I wanted to display it using the float_time widget, so I used the code `<span t-esc="ot10_total" t-options="{'widget': 'float_time'}"/>, which worked, and it now shows as 1758:55.`

Now, I'd like to combine both features - having commas in the ot10_total value and displaying it with the float_time widget. I attempted to use the code
`<span t-esc="'{0:,.2f}'.format(ot10_total)" t-options="{'widget': 'float_time'}"/>` but it resulted in an error: TypeError: bad operand type for abs(): 'str'. How can I fix this?"

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by formatting variable and then apply the "float_time" widget.

```
<span t-esc="float('{0:,.2f}'.format(ot10_total))" t-options="{'widget': 'float_time'}"/>
```

Comment: I try this code it have comma but value it not like widget float_time. it span value = 1,758.92 but when <span t-esc="ot10_total" t-options="{'widget': 'float_time'}"/> it show value = 1758:55 T^T

Comment: print('{0:,.2f}'.format(ot10_total)) __
# This will display as 1,758.92